# How to code PowerShell script and C# code in the same script

Tags: c#, powershell

I know it is possible to call C# code from the PowerShell script by loading an assembly. But is there any way to pass and receive a value in between both C# code and PowerShell script.

Let's say I have a `$path` variable in my power script. I want to pass it to my c# code. And C# code will use the $path. After doing some stuff in the c# code it will return some value to the script. Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it? I must load a third party dll in my power shell and all one or two public methods on that dll to complete some task.

My PowerShell script code:

```
    $scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
    $cureentDir = Split-Path $scriptpath;
    $isSasDir = $cureentDir -match "mydir";
    $requiredFile = "Core.dll";
    $myPowersehllVal = "has value for c# code";
```

My C# code:

```
$Source = @"
    using System.Net;

    public class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
    {
        String myPowersehllVal;
        public int Timeout;
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri address)
        {

        }
     }
"@;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C# To Return Data From PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28844580/1630171).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a  server written in C# code for bootstrapping few stuffs. That sever task is complicated to redo by ps script. I just need to call that server code. But I must pass some value from my script.

Comment: For getting PS values into C#, can't you just pass as arguments? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22384009/3546415

Comment: You can use `Add-Type` with your `$Source` variable to access that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting PS values into C#

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22384009/3546415

---

In a more general sense, [System.Management.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) ([Nuget Required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186270/3546415)) looks promising, in particular, [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) and [Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

Here are some good examples of usage:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706576(v=vs.85).aspx

Something like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706580(v=vs.85).aspx) seems similar to what you want.

Or maybe just use the [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) to execute PS commands from your C# module to set PS variable values.

---

Alternatively, without worrying about interop, you can kind of hack this by working through the file system and/or environmental variables. Following this paradigm, you could even use a [memory mapped file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) and share variables with a broader set of applications. Powershell side would be [something like this](https://github.com/dmoore44/Powershell/blob/master/memory-mapped-files.ps1). For objects, [serialization](https://coders-corner.net/2013/03/22/inter-process-communication-with-memory-mapped-files-part-01-transfer-a-data-structure-and-an-object/).